# Puedo ver en consola el cambio de tamaño de una imagen al hacerle zoom en FLUTTER?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estoy utilizando InteractiveViewer() para hacer zoom y añadir mas interactividad a las imágenes, puedo de alguna manera ver en la consola el cambio de tamaño que tiene la imagen al hacerle zoom??

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si revisas la documentación oficial: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html

Encontrarás que tiene callbacks para obtener la escala actual de la imagen :

```dart
onInteractionEnd → void Function(ScaleEndDetails details)
Called when the user ends a pan or scale gesture on the widget. [...]


onInteractionStart → void Function(ScaleStartDetails details)
Called when the user begins a pan or scale gesture on the widget. [...]


onInteractionUpdate → void Function(ScaleUpdateDetails details)
```

Podrías usarlo así :

```dart
InteractiveViewer(
  onInteractionUpdate: (details){
    print('detalle de la escala : $details');
  }
),
```